# Equivalent of java arrays.copyOf() in python

Tags: python, java, list

I have to translate a java lib into a python one.

During that process i came across the [arrays.copyOf()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf-byte:A-int-) function (the one for bytes not string).

From Docs:

> ```
> public static byte[] copyOf(byte[] original, int newLength)
> ```
>
> Returns: a copy of the original array, truncated or padded with zeros to obtain the specified length

I would like to know if there is a built in equivalent of it or if there is a lib that does it.

`my_data[some_int:some_int]` is the equivalent of java `copyOfRange()`
Here I need to output specific length bytes or byte array that will be padded with 0 if too short

Comment: Hey @Bastien B, is this what you are looking for? https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-list-copy-method/

Comment: @VictorSaraivaRocha `array.copyOf` has 2 arguments. The second argument specifies the length of the new array.

Comment: @Bastien I have edited your question. Feel free to revert the changes if not ok.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can do this in two steps,

- Create a copy of the given list.
- We can use slice assignment to return a list of size specified by the second arg.

```
def copy_of(lst, length):
    out = lst.copy() # This is a shallow copy. 
                     # For deepcopy use `copy.deepcopy(lst)`
    out[length:] = [0 for _ in range(length - len(lst))]
    return out

l = [1, 2, 3]
print(copy_of(l, 5))
# [1, 2, 3, 0, 0]

print(copy_of(l, 2))
# [1, 2]
```

Comment: thank you @Ch3steR, i ended up using it with a bytearray lst and it worked like a charm :D